# Howto handle packaging and development in one git repository?

Tags: packaging, git, pbuilder, git-buildpackage

From my point of view at the moment git-buildpackage is only intended for using upstream sources which are not in the same repository. 
I already have a git-buildpackage repository with the branches "master", "upstream and a tags from the initial import via git-import-orig.

I cant find a howto, to have a development branch in the repository and import the changes from there into the upstream branch and make it buildable by git-buildpackage. I think the answer lies behind the steps git-import-orig does with the repository, which i dont know yet.

Any suggestions about having one repository which is git-buildpacke compliant and can be used to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a section in the git-buildpackage documentation [matching your use case](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.import.html#GBP.IMPORT.UPSTREAM-GIT).

Basically, the difference is that, when importing a new release into your debian branch, you will merge modifications from a tag corresponding to the new release of your software instead of a tarball. As no tarball is involved, **there is no need to use git-import-orig**.

Just make sure that your branches and tag naming matches what git-buildpackage expects. If this is not the case, you will have to override the default configuration with your own configuration file. The syntax is explained in the documentation and the configuration file is searched at various locations. See [git-buildpackage man page](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1%20git-buildpackage) to know where (section CONFIGURATION FILES).